# What's the differences between require() and http.get()?

Tags: node.js, angular, assets

I need an external config file for my angular 15 app, so I've created a file `src/assets/config.json` which I'm currently loading with `this.httpClient.get<Config>('/assets/config.json')` during app initialization.

Could I load my file with NodeRequire : `require('src/assets/config.json')` ? This seems to be instantaneous contrary to httpClient.

Comment: I think you've verified that you _can_, so is your question about whether you _should_?

Comment: Yeah, is require() less reliable than http request?

Answer (score 0):

I assume httpClient is the client to retrieve the json through http, and require is only for retrieving in the same instance (locally).  If it's dynamic file we don't usually use require, if it's a static file always exist in the source, you probably can, but it's really rare.

Comment: `config.json` will always be in assets. I need to get it for an app translation module initialisation, but an http request is too long...